# Primefaces Tree Table highlight child rows

Tags: css, primefaces, treetable

I want to highlight child rows in different color using CSS to differentiate parent/child rows.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-default-primefaces-css-with-custom-styles

Comment: Sorry this link doesn't have solution for my question. I am unable to highlight child rows in different color with CSS.

Answer (score 1):

When you use your browser's DOM inspector, you'll notice that table rows (`tr`) of a `p:treeTable` are classed with `ui-node-level-n`. N is the level, starting at 1. So root items are level 1, children of level 1 are level 2 and so on. To have white root nodes and yellow child nodes, you can use the following CSS rules:

```css
html body .ui-treetable .ui-treetable-data>tr {
    background: yellow;
}
body .ui-treetable .ui-treetable-data>tr.ui-node-level-1 {
    background: white;
}
```

See also:

- [How do I override default PrimeFaces CSS with custom styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-default-primefaces-css-with-custom-styles)

Comment: Thank you so much , but parent row color overrides child row color. Basically both parent and child rows are highlighted in yellow.

Comment: Nope. I've tested this with the showcase and verified that it is working.